# Grab a specific HashMap entity and grab details

Tags: java, hashmap

Here are my classes:

**HouseDetails:**

```
private String forename;
private String surname;
private double houseName;
private int numberofHouses;


public CreditCardDetails(String forename, String surname, double houseName, int numberofHouses) {
    this.forename = forename;
    this.surname = surname;
    this.houseName = houseName;
    this.numberofHouses = numberofHouses;
}
```

**HousePurchase:**

```
 HashMap <String, HouseDetails> houses = new HashMap<String, HouseDetails>();
```

This is just an example.
I'm trying to see if the houseNumber first exists, and then check if the houseNumber is associated with the numberOfHouses.

This is what i have tried so far:

```
public void checkIfHouseMatches(String number ,int numberofHouses){
    for (HouseDetails det : houses.values()) 
        if (houses.containsKey(number) && det.getNumberofHouses() == numberOfHouses) {
            System.out.println("True");
        }
        else {
        }
```

However, this returns true if the numberofHouses matches any of the entities within the HashMap, instead of the specific house number that i have entered.

How do i fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your check is wrong.

What you are doing right now will check if the map contains the number and if any `HouseDetails` has `numberOfHouses` which you passed, it will return true

Suppose you have 3 house details

```
HouseDetail1 (number = 1, noOfHouses = 5)
HouseDetail2 (number = 2, noOfHouses = 6)
HouseDetail3 (number = 3, noOfHouses = 5)
```

and you searched for number 1 and noOfHouses = 6
First iteration will ll be false, because `houses.containsKey(number)` is `true` but  `det.getNumberofHouses() == numberOfHouses` is `false`

Second iteration both will be `true` -- but this is wrong. Change it to something like :

```
if(houses.containsKey(number)){
     if(houses.get(number).getNumberofHouses() == numberOfHouses){
         System.out.println("True");
     }else{
    }
 }
```

Comment: My bad. Just corrected it. Still having the same issue with it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the details from a specific entry in the HashMap, you use the `get(Object key)` method. In your case the checkIfHouseMatches can be implemented as:

```
return houses.containsKey(number) ? houses.get(number).getNumberofHouses() == numberofHouses : false;
```

No need to iterate over the values of the map.

Comment: This is close, but you need to account for the case in which `number` is not in the map.

Comment: Agreed, the other answer has houses.containsKey(number), which is correct.